# How to increase UINavigationBar height?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y
```

This is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the height/color or any other UI property of Navigation bar in your app delegate's `didFinishWithLaunchOptions` method using `[UINavigation appearance]`. You can find many options to customise navigation bar in class `UINavigation`